# Angular Material Image List Quilted How To?

Tags: angular, material-design, imagelist

Trying to get my Angular 6 application, with material design to have an Image List that has the "quilted" design.

Does anyone have an example on how I can achieve this please?

This is where I have looked:
[Material IO Site - Design -Components - Image Lists](https://material.io/design/components/image-lists.html)

It shows various types of Image Lists: Standard, Quilted, Woven and Masonry.

I really like the look of the Quilted style but can't find anywhere what html elements I need to add for the quilted view and how I do this in Angular 6.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Angular Material Grid List**](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples) for that. You can achieve this Quilted Style look by playing with the `colspan` and `rowspan` attribute bindings.

Here's an example on doing that:

**Template:**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
  <mat-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

**Component:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class GridListDynamicExample {
  tiles: any[] = [
    {text: 'One', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'Two', cols: 1, rows: 2, color: 'lightgreen'},
    {text: 'Three', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightpink'},
    {text: 'Four', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'},
  ];
}
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-list-images?file=app/grid-list-dynamic-example.ts) for your ref.